# Pallid colors in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, color

While making an PBR Orange in blender cycles, I found the problem that the material color was very pallid. I don't know how to make a more appetising material so I came here in order to solve this problem. The model is iluminated by a plane with and emission shader. In the following image you can see in the top-left corner the actual CG orange, in the top-right corner the color I want to have and in the bottom the material node

[image]

Here's a quick explanation of the material. At the bottom a procedural bumb mapping generator for the orange conected to the displacement of the material, in the middle the color of the material (a noise texture to give a bit of variation) and at the top fresnel with a sistem to control the amount the of fresnel.

Comment: Consider using the same roughness for fresnel and glossy (if you want your material to work under multiple lighting conditions). Find a kitchen HDRI with a bright window, it seems that was the case for the right. Don't overlay a general noise over the color, the orange will only reflect certain color (more than one, but not all). You will need to use SubsurfaceScattering or Translucency. Look at the reference, the leaf covers a part, but the peel returns a vivid orange at the edge, meaning that the color underneath the surface is more of red, while it contains more green at the top > yellowish

Comment: Also, are you using Filmic Blender (you should) ?

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to the organic shaders, my first try so I didn't try subsurface scatering, I'll try to find a way to do it. I'm going to do what you said about using the same roughness for the fresnel and glossy. I wouldn't use and HRDI of an interior scene, I prefer using an exterior one for preview. Thanks for your help, you made a new user happy

Comment: I would also look into using the new Principled Shader in Blender 2.79. It is one shader that is more artistic friendly and easier to tweak.

Comment: Consider use Filmic Color Management to improve the colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just need better lighting. It's best to use an [HDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-dynamic-range_imaging) image to light your scene. A good place to get them is [HDRI Haven](https://hdrihaven.com), which has low-resolutions for free (licensed CC-BY), and sells higher-resolution versions. It also has a small but growing collection of public-domain (CC0) ones.

For quick, basic lighting, I often use this HDR image, which should work pretty well here:
http://graphicslearning.com/downloads/hdr-light-probe-01-cc0/

**UPDATE 2018**: HDRI Haven has now changed its model. It's now completely public-domain at all resolutions!